# OR sql query doesnt work in java system-searching for data in column

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have a java class that is supposed to display a table. So i want to search FROM table called Film the filmtitle and the film genre but the OR query doesn't work? any idea how to fix this?

heres my code btw

```
public void searchbyTitle()
{
    String sql = "SELECT filmtitle, filmyear, filmgenre, companyname FROM production, film, 
company  WHERE LOWER(filmtitle) like LOWER
 (?) OR LOWER(filmgenre) like LOWER (?) and production.companyid = company.companyid AND production.filmid = film.filmid";
    con = DBConnect.getConnection();

    try
    {
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, "%" +txtSearch.getText()+"%");
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    }catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

it only works if i remove the or,but i also want to be able to search for film genre
LOWER is also what i used so that it will be case insensitive also used postgresql..any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The logic is doing exactly what you are telling MySQL to do.  It is just not what you intend.

If you are having trouble with conditional expressions, then use parentheses to explicitly do what you want:

```
WHERE (LOWER(filmtitle) like LOWER (?) OR
       LOWER(filmgenre) like LOWER (?)
      ) and
      production.companyid = company.companyid AND production.filmid = film.filmid;
```

Ouch!  I notice that you have commas in the `FROM` clause.  If you had used explicit `JOIN` syntax, your query would have been correct to begin with.  The correct way to write the query is:

```
SELECT filmtitle, filmyear, filmgenre, companyname
FROM production p JOIN
     film f
     ON p.filmid = f.filmid JOIN
     company c
     ON p.companyid = c.companyid
WHERE LOWER(filmtitle) like LOWER(?) OR LOWER(filmgenre) like LOWER(?);
```

Notice the parentheses are no longer needed in the `WHERE`, because there is no `AND` competing with the `OR`.

Simple rule: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  It would have saved you a lot of time today.

Comment: Yeah, so many people confuse the precedence of `OR` vs `AND`, so rule of thumb: *Always* use parenthesis when mixing `OR` and `AND`, even if *you* understand the precedence rules. --- Even though I just used "always", saying "never use comma" is a bit extreme, but a good rule of thumb. ;-)

Comment: thanks for answering but an error still pops if it helps...it looks like this No value specified for parameter 1.
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.checkAllParametersSet(SimpleParameterList.java:216)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:244)
 at

Comment: org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
 at film.FilmIntro.searchbyTitle(FilmIntro.java:111)
 at film.FilmIntro$4.keyReleased(FilmIntro.java:196)

Comment: In your request you are using two ? so you have  to define two parameters in your java code : pst.setString(...

Comment: That can  be same value : pst.setString(1, "%" +txtSearch.getText()+"%"); pst.setString(2, "%" +txtSearch.getText()+"%");